# Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw although I have already changed the path

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin

I followed a youtube tutorial and the problem is that I now get the following error when starting the application in Eclipse:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:266)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:278)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    ... 5 more.
```

None of the posts listed so far have helped me. :(

Comment: yes I did already. Do I have to install Java JDK on windows or is it just fine to implement it in Eclipse? Could it be a problem if I have added the JRE System Libary with JavaSE-17 and in the classpath Java SDK 18.01 jar files?

Comment: if Eclipse is starting, the java jdk is reachable  :) No, any version >= 11 will be okay

Comment: btw: why the eclipse-plugin tag? do you develop plugins? If not, remove it please

Comment: "Could it be a problem if I have added the JRE System Libary with JavaSE-17 and in the classpath Java SDK 18.01 jar files?" I am not sure what you actually mean but it looks like calling for disaster. (But this is not JavaFX related or did you mean JavaFX SDK?)

Comment: yeah sorry I mean JavaFX SDK

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is [issue #237](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/237) related?

Comment: JavaFX should be on the module path, not the class path, this is documented in the documentation linked in the first comment.  If you continue to have issues, you should edit your question to add more info on your runtime environment (OS, JDK, JavaFX versions) as well as adding the full command line used to execute your application (formatted as code), and anything else which might help somebody replicate your issue.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your hints. Ultimately it was the path to start. I moved the external jars and suddenly it started.